# How to embed a php function within an echo?

Tags: php

I want to list blogs with user membership on user home page as  or whatever possible tag. yet I want every listed blog to launch a divert() function onClick. This function should assign a new `$_SESSION[]` variable, and then redirect the user to the `blog.php` (blog page). In the code below, `divert()` function launch once I call the home page.

```
include_once("inc/dbconnect.php");
session_start();

function divert($x) {

    $_SESSION['blnm'] = $x;
    header("Location: blog.php");
}

function listing() {
    global $conn;
    $member = $_SESSION['u'];

    $outquery = "SELECT * FROM blogmembership WHERE blogmember='$member'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $outquery);
    $no = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $list = $row['blogname'];

        echo "<li><a onClick='".divert($list)."' id='".$list."'>".$list."</a>    </li><br />";
        //How to launch the "divert()" function onClick only?
    }
}
```

Comment: use `'divert($list)'` instead of `'".divert($list)."'`
or use `'divert(".$list.")'` . It's also depend on `$list` value that it's a string or int

Comment: a string,  $list carry blog name

Comment: try this once `'divert(\'".$list."\')'`

Comment: no that ain't possible, you're trying to invoke the PHP function and into the anchor link, you're confused about server and client-side scripting, the only way to do that is thru XMLHttpRequest